# StretchBlt fails with multiple windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

So I have the following code:

```
HBITMAP tbmp=NULL;
HBITMAP cbmp=NULL;
tbmp=hbmp;// hbmp is defined earlier
cbmp=hbmp;
HDC h1=GetDC(mainWind);//main wind defined earlier
HDC h2=GetDC(secondWind);// secondWind defined earlier
HDC h1mem=CreateCompatibleDC(h1);
HDC h2mem= CreateCompatibleDC(h2);
SelectObject(h1mem, tbmp);
SelectObject(h2mem, cbmp);
StretchBlt(h1, 300, 0, 384, 216, h1mem, 0,0,1920,1080);
StretchBlt(h2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, h2mem, 0,0,1920,1080);
```

However, when I run this, only the first `StretchBlt` does anything. No matter what order I put them in, only the first `StretchBlt` creates anything. I could really use some help. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have the same `HBITMAP` handle selected in more than one device context. Just because you copied the same handle value into three different variables doesn't mean that you now magically have three distinct handles - you just have three copies of the same handle. Most likely, the second `SelectObject` call fails (generally, you should check return values of all API calls).

Try it this way:

```
HDC h1 = GetDC(mainWind);
HDC h2 = GetDC(secondWind);
HDC h1mem = CreateCompatibleDC(h1);
HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(h1mem, hbmp);

StretchBlt(h1, 300, 0, 384, 216, h1mem, 0,0,1920,1080);
StretchBlt(h2, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, h1mem, 0,0,1920,1080);

// Cleanup
SelectObject(h1mem, hbmOld);
DeleteDC(h1mem);
ReleaseDC(h1);
ReleaseDC(h2);
```